# How to scrape a website that uses ajax based pagination with python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape reviews from this page https://www.influenster.com/reviews/garnier-fructis-sleek-shine-anti-frizz-serum-89. Website is built with React and pagination for reviews is totally ajax based. I tried selenium to click to next button and wait for page to change. Everything working OK but the problem I am facing is that it makes the process very slow as I have to wait for about 10-20 seconds for each request. This product has 19,664 reviews and imagine how much time I have to wait for one product and there are 238084 products.
I also inspect network tab to find request URL and it was this https://www.influenster.com/reviews/garnier-fructis-sleek-shine-anti-frizz-serum-89?paginate=true&review_page=15&sort=featured and when I tried to hit this in postman, I get HTML instead of JSON. Any help will be highly appreciated. I'm currently using selenium with beautifulSoup. 
I know these types of questions answered many types but I tried all possible solution. 
Here is my function to scrape reviews

```
 def scrape_reviews(self, soup, product_id):
    total_reviews = soup.select('.list-title h3')[0].get_text().strip().split(" ", 1)[0]
    pagination = soup.select('.pagination-page-list')[0].findChildren('li')
    total_review_pages = pagination[len(pagination) - 2].get_text().strip()
    current_reviews = soup.select('.search__ReviewWrapper-sc-1ylxfoz-1 .item')
    temp_reviews_ = self.parse_reviews(current_reviews, product_id)
    self.temp_total_rating += temp_reviews_.get('rating')
    self.temp_total_reviews += temp_reviews_.get('reviews')

    n = int(total_review_pages)

    def click_on_links(i, j):
        # global total_rating, review_count
        if i < j:
            # click_n_wait(self.driver, self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@aria-label="Page ' + str(i) + '"]'))
            click_n_wait(self.driver, self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.next a'))
            sleep(20)
            new_soup = self.get_soup_from_driver()
            current_reviews1 = new_soup.select('.search__ReviewWrapper-sc-1ylxfoz-1 .item')

            _temp_reviews = self.parse_reviews(current_reviews1, product_id)
            self.temp_total_rating += _temp_reviews.get('rating')
            self.temp_total_reviews += _temp_reviews.get('reviews')
            click_on_links(i + 1, j)
        else:
            return False

    click_on_links(1, n)
    print('click finished...')

    return {
        'rating': self.temp_total_rating,
        'reviews': self.temp_total_reviews
    }
```

Here is function `click_and_wait`

```
def click_n_wait(driver, button, timeout=5):
source = driver.page_source
button.click()

def compare_source(driver):
    try:
        return source != driver.page_source
    except WebDriverException:
        pass
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(compare_source)
```

Comment: paste some example code, do you expect people to give you ready-for-use solution ?

Comment: @Infern0 OK, I paste some code there. Now please have a look